# Timeline change custom int property

Tags: qt, qml

My goal is to design a simple circular progress bar, that uses an arc and a text to represent a value. I am using the Qt Designer for this.

I managed to "animate" the arc, but I can not dynamically change the text. My idea was to add an int property to the text that gets modified by the timeline, but nothing happens. I tried this with

```
Text {
    id: valueText
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: displayValue.toString()
    font.pixelSize: 35

    property int displayValue: 0
}
```

and

```
Text {
    id: valueText
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: qsTr("0%")
    font.pixelSize: 35

    property int displayValue: 0
        
    onDisplayValueChanged {
        text: displayValue.toString()
        }
    }
```

but both didn't work.

Full source:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Studio.Components 1.0
import QtQuick.Timeline 1.0

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    property alias progressValue: timeline.currentFrame

    ArcItem {
        id: arc
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        fillColor: "#00000000"

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        strokeColor: "#25a219"
        antialiasing: true
        smooth: true
        end: -150
        begin: -150
        strokeWidth: 15
    }

    Text {
        id: valueText
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: displayValue.toString()
        font.pixelSize: 35

        property int displayValue: 0
    }

    Timeline {
        id: timeline
        endFrame: 100
        startFrame: 0
        enabled: true

        KeyframeGroup {
            target: arc
            property: "end"
            Keyframe {
                value: 150
                frame: 100
            }

            Keyframe {
                value: -150
                frame: 0
            }
        }
        KeyframeGroup {
            target: valueText
            property: "displayValue"
            Keyframe {
                value: 0
                frame: 0
            }

            Keyframe {
                value: 100
                frame: 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I use the wrong type for the property, but by making it a string, it only changes between 0 and 100 at the keyframes.

Workaround found:
Using the timeline frame as an indicator for the value. This only works here, because I want a value in % and my timeline has 100 frames. I'm still interested in how this could work with the keyframes though.

```
Text {
    id: valueText
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: timeline.currentFrame + "%"
    font.pixelSize: 35
}
```

Comment: TYPO: change to `text = displayValue.toString()`

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Don't i assign values with ```property: value```?

Comment: I point out that there is a TYPO in the second code you provide. `onDisplayValueChanged {  text: displayValue.toString() }`

Comment: make `x: y` is not an assignment but a binding, an assignment is `x = y`, the difference is that the first indicates that if you change "y" then "x" will be updated, in the second case only the one-time value. Bindings are done when a property is declared, not in functions

Comment: But shouldn't the first code snippet work then? If I bind ```text``` to my custom property, it should update every time the timeline changes the value of the property. Or is it the ```.toString()``` that prevents it from working, because I would bind it to a string? But it doesn't work without the conversion either. It just writes #displayValue#.